# Expectation of Product of 2 Random Variables

Tags: probability

[image]

What is the joint density function here?

Comment: It seems the joint density function is 1, but where does it come from?

Comment: I'm guessing you're missing a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ in the solution.

Comment: No wonder I got confused, 1/2 is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the law of the unconcious statistican (LOTUS):
$$E[g(X)] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) f(x) dx$$ where $f(x)$ is the density of $X$ and $g(X)$ is a random variable which is some function of $X$. This allows us to calculate moments of functions of a random variable without calculating its distribution. Note that $X_t$, $X_{t-h}$ (and thus $X_t X_{t-h}$) are functions of $V$, so LOTUS can be applied.

So, $E[X_t X_{t-h}] =E[ \cos(2 \pi (t/12 + V)) \cos(2 \pi ( (t-h)/12 + V))]$ $= \int_\mathbb{R} \cos(2 \pi (t/12 + v)) \cos(2 \pi ( (t-h)/12 + v)) f(v) dv=$ $\int_0^2 \cos(2 \pi (t/12 + v)) \cos(2 \pi ( (t-h)/12 + v)) \frac{1}{2} dv$

since $f(v) = \frac{1}{2}$ on $[0,2]$ and $0$ otherwise.

(Similarly, $E[X_t] = E[ \cos(2 \pi (t/12 + V))] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \cos(2 \pi (t/12 + v)) f(v) dv = \int_0^2 \cos(2 \pi (t/12 + v)) \frac{1}{2} dv = 0$.

(*) LOTUS was used by S.M. Ross in his introductory probability text, but statisticians wrote to him cause they found the name offensive and thus it does not appear there anymore.

Comment: Any source about the LOTUS anecdote?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math/0juhaZGojRI is the closest thing I could find with a quick google. I heard the anecdote from several probabilists and statisticians that I know.